# AWS Glue Dev Endpoint - Cache Virtual Env

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-glue-workflow

I'm using the AWS Glue Dev Endpoint.  It takes a while for the python virtualenv stuff to be uploaded.  Is there a way that I can cache these files to tighten the development loop?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the Dev Endpoint method of development has been superceded by using a Docker environment.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/developing-aws-glue-etl-jobs-locally-using-a-container/